# Connecting to ActiveMQ STOMP over websocket with python

Tags: python, websocket, activemq-classic, stomp

I have following ActiveMQ configuration at server side, basically stomp over websocket. Is there any way to connect and start consuming messages from queues with any existing Python libraries? Or What I am missing?

```
<transportConnector name="websocket" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:31614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600" />
```

I have tried multiple python (stomp.py, stompest), but I cannot connect to broker. At server side this is seen as:

```
broker-amq 2018-10-28 18:18:09,130 | WARN  | badMessage: 400 No URI for HttpChannelOverHttp@35c228e5{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=} | org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser | qtp428039780-131
```

My implementations with stomp.py:

```
class QueueListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):

def __init__(self, queueConnector):
    self.connector = queueConnector
def on_error(self, headers, message):
    self.connector.add_error(message)
def on_message(self, headers, message):
    self.connector.add_message(message)

class AMQHandler:

def __init__(self):
    self.connection = None
    self.queue = None
    self.messages = []
    self.errors = []
    self.listener = QueueListener(self)

def connect_to_broker(self, host, port, user, password):
    if self.connection != None:
        print "Old connection still active! Closing it..."
        self.disconnect_broker()
    self.connection = stomp.connect.StompConnection12(host_and_ports=[(host, port)])
    self.connection.set_listener('', self.listener)
    self.connection.start()
    self.connection.connect(username=user, passcode=password, wait=False, headers=None)

connector = AMQHandler()
connector.connect_to_broker("brokeraddress", 31614, "someone@somewhere.com", "xxxxx")
```

My implementation with stompest.py:

```
CONFIG = StompConfig('tcp://brokeraddress:31614', version=StompSpec.VERSION_1_2)
QUEUE = '/queue/test'

client = Stomp(CONFIG)
client.connect(headers={'passcode': 'xxxxx', 'login': 'someone@somewhere.com'})
client.connect()
client.subscribe(QUEUE, {StompSpec.ACK_HEADER: StompSpec.ACK_CLIENT_INDIVIDUAL})
while True:
    frame = client.receiveFrame()
    print('Got %s' % frame.info())
    client.ack(frame)
client.disconnect()
```

Comment: The broker appears to be listening for connections on port `61614`, but your client is using `31614`. What happens if you use `61614` on the client?

Comment: Sorry ..  yeah that is docker container and exposed as service in kubernetes in port 31614. I will remove this avoid confusion.

Comment: How do you know it's not a problem between the host platform and docker that's preventing the connection?  What happens if you run the broker and the client on the same host? Also, are you getting any errors on the client? If so, what are they?

Comment: I guess this is getting out of the track :) Please focus on stomp over websocket. Currently all clients are connecting via TCP. I run both locally as I'm debugging this issue.

Comment: So...are you getting any errors on the client? If so, what are they?  Also, what version of ActiveMQ are you using? ActiveMQ 5.x ships with stomp examples (including Python) in the `examples/stomp` directory.  Have you tried any of those?  If so, what was the result?  If not, why not?

Comment: I have no problems connecting to ActimeMQ with transportConnector name="stomp" but I cannot connect to broker with configured as transportConnector name="websocket" (Stomp over websocket).

Comment: From what I can tell this is a client-side issue. I just tested a default ActiveMQ 5.x instance with the [stomp-websocket](https://github.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket) browser tests and (after changing the test password) everything worked fine.  I think the problem is that the clients you're trying to use simply don't support STOMP over websockets.

Comment: Yeah after playing around with netcat I saw that libraries are pure STOMP. Websocket based I can see HTTP request first. Are there then libraries that supports then stomp over websocket in Python? .. I actually today implemented myself websocket proxy as workaround. I wish I could use some library directly (like js/ruby there are).

Comment: I implement websocket proxy as solution. I will paste my solution later.

Comment: hi @tiny, could you please share your solution here? I really need this.